# Characters Missing from files created with Windows Notepad

Tags: windows, unicode, url, notepad, characters

Plain text files that I have previously saved, and not modified or moved, using Windows Notepad, now have characters missing. The URL in each .txt file has the same characters missing, the colon and forward slash. Any ideas?

Text File 1

http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskMark/index-e.html

Has become:

httpcrystalmark.infosoftwareCrystalDiskMarkindex-e.html

---

Text File 2

http://www.overclock.net/t/1227597/how-to-secure-erase-your-solid-state-drive-ssd-with-parted-magic

Has become:

httpwww.overclock.nett1227597how-to-secure-erase-your-solid-state-drive-ssd-with-parted-magic

---

This is my routine; I download software, for example BleachBit, from say SourceForge and save it to a folder. Then in the same folder I create a new plain text file using Windows Notepad. I copy the URL of the software I have downloaded from Firefox, and paste the URL into the newly created text file. The reason being, someone else can see exactly where the software originated if there is a problem with the installation. Only 2% of the text files that I have created are exhibiting the above behavior. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same effect if you `TYPE` the files from a command prompt? Notepad is sometimes too smart for its own good...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Perhaps, but I've *never* seen it do this.

Comment: @Morpheus: Did you open these files even once after saving to confirm they were ok?

Comment: @Karan: This is my routine; I download software, for example BleachBit, from say SourceForge and save it to a folder. Then in the same folder I create a new plain text file using Windows Notepad. I copy the URL of the software I have downloaded from Firefox, and paste the URL into the newly created text file. The reason being, someone else can see exactly where the software originated if there is a problem with the installation. Only 2% of the text files that I have created are exhibiting the above behavior.

Comment: There's some back and forth going on here. We work differently from forums that you may be used to; comments are used to request additional information or suggest clarifications; answers are reserved strictly for answers to the question as asked; and all information relevant for answering the question should go into the question itself, with possibly an @-ping comment to draw the requester's attention to the post edit. Please take the site [tour] to learn more about how we do things here, and check out [the help center section on asking questions](http://superuser.com/help/asking) for more.

Comment: @Morpheus: Ok, but you still didn't answer my question. Even for the 2% damaged files, did you ever at any point ensure after saving that the contents were as expected? I'm trying to narrow down whether this could have happened during saving (which would point to Notepad as the culprit), or later. The puzzling thing is that even if it happened later due to say a failing HDD, the corruption would be random and not like this.

Comment: Please do not simply rollback edits that help your question. Comments are transient and subject to deletion and your question should be the true source for all the information pertaining to your problem. This is not a forum and as such we have different standards for content. Please consider taking the [tour].

Comment: @ Karan: Apologies, I should have finished the reply with - Only 2% of the text files that I created are exhibiting the above behavior. All of the text files were created at the same time. None of the text files were opened at the time of creation. The only time the text files were opened was just before creating this thread, when I found 2% of them in this format. I will take a tour of super user asap, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- You have assumed that the text files were modified *after* saving.
- All the evidence points to the clipboard text being modified
  by Explorer *prior* to pasting
  (but unless you are looking very closely at the time
  you won't notice the stripped characters).
- In your 2 examples the only characters that have been removed are : and /.
  These are invalid filename characters.
- They have most likely been removed, at times when the url was on the clipboard.
  You accidentally pasted while naming a file in Explorer,
  and the invalid filename characters were stripped from the clipboard contents at that time.
  Then when you pasted the text into Notepad, unbeknownst to you,
  some of the characters had already been removed.